# Add empty (blank) space under (in the end of) UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

My app has the `UITableView` which have variable quantity of cells inside.

How can I add empty (blank) space with certain height under the `UITableView`? Or in the very end of `UITableView`? So that after the very last cell there will be more blank space.

Comment: Add `tbl_view.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];` in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Set the content inset on your table view:

```
var insets: UIEdgeInsets = tableView.contentInset
insets.bottom = 100
tableView.contentInset = insets
```

or, simply:

```
tableView.contentInset.bottom = 100
```

That will leave some blank space under the table view after you scroll to the last cell.

Comment: you sir are a Mustache 

Comment: Or simply `self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 100`

Comment: It is perfect answer.. Thanks

Comment: @Siklab.ph , you're the only person on this whole page who knows how to do this  :)

Comment: This answer is really not right.  You're changing the other insets, which is almost always not what you want to do.

Comment: @Fattie you are absolutely right about other anchors. But this answer is just example of how you can achieve bottom inset, not silver bullet for all problems of this world

Comment: I'm really sorry but this is ***just wrong***.  It will break a number of other things. Siklab.ph has given the simple correct answer.  I mention this for the sake of people googling to this 10,000 view QA.

Comment: @Siklab.ph I wish you earned points from my upvote. Thanks for the simple answer mate.

Answer (score 29):

## It's honestly this simple:

Add the following, likely in `viewDidLoad`:

## `tableView.contentInset.bottom = 100`

Really that's all there is to it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    tableView.contentInset.bottom = 100
}
```

Comment: For any Obj-C dinosaurs out there

`UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 0.0);

    [self.tableView setContentInset:insets];`

Order is 'Top, Left, Bottom, Right'

Comment: Super duper easy solution and works just fine. Thanks.

Comment: As u said this solution was very easy and working fine. Tested in iOS 15 & 16

Answer (score 11):

You can use `tableView` `Footer` for that

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 100)];
[self.tableView setTableFooterView:view];
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @Siklab.ph for me the best answer.

```
self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 100
```

Comment: To be clear this is the ***only correct answer*** on this page  :/

Answer (score 2):

**Be careful with programmatic scrolling and bottom-blank space definition**:

One thing to consider: if you happen to use a programmatic scrolling towards a certain cell in your tableView. Then you need to add enough bottom-space to prevent the ugly looking `scrolling-and-not-having-enough-bottom-space-causing-up-and-down-jumping-of-your-cells effect` (i.e. it really all depends on your scrolling code - I just wanted to mention it).

**So it could actually be a good idea to make your extra-space a multiple of your cellHeight** (and if programmatic scrolling then add the correct multiple of your cellHeight as extra space)...

The already mentioned solutions are shorter than my solution. But if you need extra customization of your bottom blank-space and if you don't need the tableView-footerView for other things, you might as well **use the footerView to create your extra bottom blank-space** and do :

```
let rowHeight = 70  // or whatever...
let nrOfCellHeightsSpaces = 6  // or whatever.. (consider scrolling !)
let heightDependentSpace = nrOfCellHeightsSpaces * rowHeight
let customViewFooter = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.width, height: heightDependentSpace))
customViewFooter.backgroundColor = .clear  // or whatever color
// add whatever customization of your extra bottom-space
// (such as copyrights, decent logos, product information, etc, etc)
tableView.tableFooterView = customViewFooter
```

Answer (score 2):

I honestly do not like to mess around with insets too much (especially if you are already modifying them for other reasons).

The solution I found was to override [`tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview) method and return the desired space height for the last section of the `tableView`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == lastSectionIndex {
        return 30.0
    }
    return 0.001
}
```

The last `0.001` value is for all other sections which, in my case, they do not have any footer; in this way, the footer in other sections is missing.
No extra view creation needed.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced some issues in using `footerView` when using it along with sections before, so here is another approach that worked for me, you can also try creating a custom `cell` that is just an `emptyView` and show that particular `cell` at the last index.

In `numberOfRowsInSection` just make total number of rows as one more than total number of rows you want to show.

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can do something like-

```
if(indexPath.row == size + 1){
     //show custom cell
}
```

Comment: yeah don't do this

Answer (score -2):

Just add a blank clear view to the bottom of your table in storyboard.